# Search function resizing in ActionBar Kivy Python 3

Tags: android, python, kivy

Working with Kivy ActionBar, and i've successfully created a Search widget. The only problem is there is a lot of open space left in the ActionBar once I add the Search input.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput 
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""

<RootWidget>:
    ActionBar:
        background_color: .5, .7, .6, 1
        size_hint_y: .10
        pos_hint: {'top':1}
        ActionView:

            ActionPrevious:
                with_previous: False 
                SearchBar:
                    size_hint_x: 1
                    size_hint_y: .5
                    pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'center_y':.5}
                    on_text_validate: searchbutt.trigger_action()

                ActionButton:
                    icon: "search.png"
                    size_hint_x: None
                    size_hint_y: None
                    size: (30,30)
                    pos_hint: {'x': .3, 'center_y': .5}
                    id: searchbutt

            ActionOverflow:
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Btn1'
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Btn2'
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Btn3'

""")
class RootWidget(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RootWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    pass

class SearchBar(TextInput, ActionItem):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SearchBar, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.hint_text='Enter Location'
    def search(self):
        request = self.text
        return str(request)


class VerticalPanes(BoxLayout):
    orientation= 'vertical'
    pass
class HorizontalPanes(BoxLayout):
    pass
class EventScreen(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    EventScreen().run()
```

Here is my file code, if you run it and resize the window then you can see the search bar shrinks until it is almost useless, yet empty space following the app icon is plentiful.

Also, if you see any general parts I can improve in my code/technique, lemme know.

PS: search.png is just a magnifying glass icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up figuring it out. here is the code i'm going with:

```
<RootWidget>:
    ActionBar:
        background_color: .5, .7, .6, 1
        size_hint_y: .10
        pos_hint: {'top':1}
        ActionView:
            SearchBar:
                size_hint_x: 1.7
                size_hint_y: .5
                pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'center_y':.5}
                on_text_validate: searchbutt.trigger_action()

            ActionButton:
                text: 'Map'

            ActionPrevious:
                with_previous: False

            ActionOverflow:
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Filters'
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Settings'
```

Figured out i just had to move the position of ActionPrevious in the kv lang code.